# Is it better to have one large file or many smaller files for data storage?

Tags: python, c++, file, server, network-programming

I have an C++ game which sends a Python-SocketIO request to a server, which loads the requested JSON data into memory for reference, and then sends portions of it to the client as necessary. Most of the previous answers here detail that the server has to repeatedly search the database, when in this case, all of the data is stored in memory after the first time, and is released after the client disconnects.

I don't want to have a large influx of memory usage whenever a new client joins, however most of what I have seen points away from using small files (50-100kB absolute maximum), and instead use large files, which would cause the large memory usage I'm trying to avoid.

My question is this: would it still be beneficial to use one large file, or should I use the smaller files; both from an organization standpoint and from a performance one?

Comment: If all your data can fit in memory, that by definition is a small file. And if it's fits in memory, that's the fastest performance you're going to get. So there is diminishing returns in improving performance from a storage point of view.

Comment: The optimizations will likely now be in how you access the file and with what patterns. Data that is stored close to each other will be access faster due to the cache refreshes.

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is the growth of data over time. If you anticipate this, you should make it a design constraint/factor and design for it now. It can be too costly and take more time to make a pivot later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it better to have one large file or many smaller files for data storage?

Both can potentially be better. Each have their advantage and disadvantage. Which is better depends on the details of the use case. It's quite possible that best way may be something in between such as a few medium sized files.

Regarding performance, the most accurate way to verify what is best is to try out each of them and measure.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate it into multiple files for less memory if you're only accessing small parts of it. For example, if you're only accessing let's say a player, then your folder structure would look like this:

```
players
  - 0.json
  - 1.json
other
  - 0.json
```

Then you could write a function that just gets the player with a certain id (0, 1, etc.).

If you're planning on accessing all of the players, other objects, and more at once, then have the same folder structure and just concatenate the parts you need into one object in memory.